# How do you group data in SQL based on a mathematical calculation?

Tags: sql, math, group-by

I am pretty good at SQL, but this is beyond me. I am looking at a database table that stores transaction records for a department store. Some transactions are purchases and some are returns. I am trying to write a query that will group the data by account, and show how many purchases the account holder has made and how many returns the account holder has made.

Here is a simplified view of the data in the Transaction_Table:

```
Account_Id  Transaction_Code    Transaction_Amt
----------        ----------------   ---------------
123               P                  20.00  
123               P                  30.00
123               R                  10.00
```

So, in English, Account_Id 123 made two purchases (the records with a Transaction_Code of "P"), worth a total of $50, and made one return (the record with a Transaction_Code of "R"), worth $10.

I wrote the following SQL query:

```
SELECT Account_Id, SUM(Transaction_Amt) AS Total_Spent
FROM Transaction_Table 
WHERE Transaction_Code IN (‘P’, ‘R’)
GROUP BY Account_Id
ORDER BY Total_Purchased
```

When I run the query, I get this:

```
Account_Id     Total_Spent
123            60.00
```

HOWEVER, what I want is something like this:

```
Account_Id     Total_Purchased     Total_Returned
123            50.00               10.00
```

Is this possible? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a kind of pivot query, where you need to `SUM()` based on the value of `Transaction_code`.

```
SELECT
  Account_Id,
  /* SUM() conditionally based on the Transaction_Code value */
  SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'P' THEN Transaction_Amt ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Purchased,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Transaction_Code = 'R' THEN Transaction_Amt ELSE 0 END) AS Total_Returned
FROM
  Transaction_Table
GROUP BY Account_Id
ORDER BY Total_Purchased
```

Here's a demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/850b3/1

Comment: Thank you, sir!!! This worked exactly as your fiddle does!!! Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!